# Constructing nested json key element

Tags: apex, json, string

Looking for an easier way to generate an element with nested attributes using the json generator. How would you generate the 'parent' element?[image]

Comment: What you want to achieve here? Is it something which will be returned by jsRemoting? If you want to do that then you can create wrapper classes in apex and return custom type from remoting method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `parent` attribute on the outer object just needs to represent an instance of another object (class).

Class Structure

```
public class Container {
    public ParentItem parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentItem {
    public String link { get; set; }
    public String value { get; set; }
}
```

Implementation

```
Container c = new Container();

c.parent = new ParentItem();
c.parent.link = 'yourURL';
c.parent.value = 'yourValue';

String cAsJSON = JSON.serialize(c);

system.debug(cAsJSON);
```

Comment: Much appreciated.